# Accessing members of a struct in array Clisp

Tags: struct, lisp, common-lisp

Imagine I have a function that receive a array of structs like this:

```
(defun name-of-func (array) 
  (dotimes (i (array-total-size array))
    (print (aref array i))))
```

and the `stuct` is something like this

```
(defstruct sTSP 
  cidade 
  x 
  y)
```

How can I access the field `x` on `i` position of the array?

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the definition of [`defstruct`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defstr.htm). 
It is long, but well worth the read.
If you are lazy, like we all are, search for `reader`:

```lisp
(defstruct foo x y z)
(defparameter foo (make-foo :x 2 :y 4))
(foo-x foo)
==> 2
(foo-y foo)
==> 4
(foo-z foo)
==> NIL
```

**PS1**. Please note that [`array-total-size`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_ar_tot.htm) should
*not* be used with [`aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_aref.htm) but
rather with [`row-major-aref`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_row_ma.htm).
The difference is with *multi-dimensional arrays* which are implemented
as [`vector`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_vector.htm)s under the hood.
E.g., your function will fail on `(make-array '(2 2) :initial-element (make-sTSP))`.

**PS2**. I re-use `foo` for *both* type name *and* variable name to illustrate that they reside is *different* name spaces.